# django-'str' object has no attribute 'ppoi'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i install django-versatileImageField package and it's working very well
but when i want change object or add new object in admin
it show this error 'str' object has no attribute 'ppoi'.
['str' object has no attribute 'ppoi'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59xao.png)

my model
[my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocAnv.png)

my code work without versatileImageField

github link= https://github.com/omidPakshekar/django-elearning-platfrom.git

Comment: You should also show some code here. How can we check your model?

Comment: Please do not post links to images of your code. Show your code as text.

Comment: @DivyaPrakash, He tell enough to answer. He Has error in decompress Method in versatileImageWidget. This Widget is Part of django-versatileImageField, why you need other code?